# How to customize model validation error message excluding column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

here is a working example of customizing error but i dont want to include the column name "fname" in the error.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      profile:
        fname: "First Name"
    errors:
      models:
        profile:
          attributes:
            fname:
              blank: "is required"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i exclude the column name from errors in rails 4.

**app/views/profiles/-form.html.erb**

```
<% if @profile.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <ul>
  <% @profile.errors.messages.values.each do |msg| %>
    <% msg.each do  |m| %>
      <li><%= m %></li>
    <%end %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**en.yml**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        profile:
          attributes:
            fname:
              blank: "Please enter your First Name to continue"
            lname:
              blank: "Please enter your Last Name to continue"
```